# After split array gives only first character

Tags: android, arrays

I have a value in the database table that I would like to split by `|` the value is `Company|company.pdf|images.pdf`. When I run the following code, it only returns `C` in the Debug.

What am I doing wrong?

```
        String cname = null;
        String cpdf = null;
        String cimages = null;
        String catGetGeneralNameSQL = "SELECT * FROM categorymeta WHERE key = 'category_general' AND company = " + dashboard_company_id;
        Cursor catGetGeneralNameQuery = myDB.rawQuery(catGetGeneralNameSQL, null);
        while(catGetGeneralNameQuery.moveToNext()){
            String name = catGetGeneralNameQuery.getString(catGetGeneralNameQuery.getColumnIndex("value"));
            String[] separated = name.split("|");
            Log.d("LOG", separated[1]);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the `split()` method take a regular expression as parameter, and `|` is a reserved character in regexp.

Try with : `\\|` to escape it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String test = "Company|company.pdf|images.pdf";
  String[] result = test.split("\\|");
  System.out.println(result[1]);
}
```

It outputs :

```
company.pdf
```

See the `split()` method documentation : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

The pipe (without being escaped) is used in regular expressions to separate alternate matching patterns, eg: `aaa|bbb` will match "aaa" or "bbb", that's why it's matching every single character when not escaped.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the original special character:

```
String[] separated = name.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 0):

use:
String[] b = a.split("\\|");

it will work fine with this